# how to open crystal reports with folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

**Here is my Report load Function:** But there is some problem. Report file in  before bin folder then properly load. but i want to all reports separately in **Report** folder

```
Private Function GetDeliveryChallanPrint() As DataTable
    Dim data As New DataTable
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VKDBx").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from DcMaster dm Left join DcDetail   dd  on dm.ID = dd.ID where dm.id = '" & PrinByIDTextBox.Text.ToString() & "'", Conn)
            Conn.Open()
            Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                adp.Fill(data)

                Dim FILEPATH As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath + "\Reports")
                Dim DcPrint As New Rpt_DeliveryChallan
                DcPrint.Load(FILEPATH)
                DcPrint.SetDataSource(data)
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DcPrint
                CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
                StatusLabel.Visible = False
                Conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities to load a Crystal Report on VB.NET:

**using the report object:**

```
Dim DcPrint As New Rpt_DeliveryChallan
DcPrint.SetDataSource(data)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DcPrint
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

**Note:** In this case you need to embed the report to the project.

**using the `ReportDocument` and load the report from file:**

```
 Dim FILEPATH As String = CurDir() & "\Reports\Rpt_DeliveryChallan.rpt"
 Dim DcPrint As New ReportDocument
 DcPrint.Load(FILEPATH)
 DcPrint.SetDataSource(data)
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DcPrint
 CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: I have a column called **checktime** which datatype is **nvarchar (50)** and contains values in the 
following format ''31/03/2017 9:23:25 AM'..

I have created a new column called **checktime1** and **checktime2**  where i want to convert the values
from Nvarchar(50) to datetime datatype format using an update statement.

I would like the data within **checktime1** to be in the following format 'YYYYMMDD' and **checktime2** in this following format 'hh:mm:tt'

Comment: Your answer is correct.
I was using the first method but now I feel the requirement of the 2nd method where I just need to change the file in case of any report changes and not the whole new exe. But the problem I facing is my crystal report viewer keeps loading in the 2nd method. I have written the code as you describe but if you want to see then I am posting a text file link below. Moreover, I am not using data table but an oledb connection

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PP9GQ22MGILJ71v4C6qjEUxkOmoi3_kv/view?usp=sharing) Please check the google drive txt link. You may view it online without downloading. Thank You..